What does this dialect mean in normal Japanaese んでどないします

「ほな皆々様！ 明るく燦々、ニコニコしましょっ。　晴れるの待ってるボクらが　お天道さんより笑わんでどないしますのっ」

The character is I suppose telling them to smile as they wait for the sun to pop out and they should laugh/smile more than the sun.
What to make of んでどないしますのっ」  though? Let's smile? We have to smile? IF we don't smile what will happen?

「笑わんでどないします」＝「笑わないでどうしますか」
'What can we do if not smile/laugh?'
Basically this turn of phrase is used to say there's no point not doing something, so you might as well

Is that a regional 方言 kind of construction?  I got as far as the 笑わんで ≅ 笑わないで part, but the どないします ≅ どうしますか equivalency escapes me.

@EiríkrÚtlendi わざわざそんなん聞いてどないすんねん

@EiríkrÚtlendi どない is どう, どんな in Kansai (そない also exists). With your breadth of knowledge I'm surprised you're unfamiliar actually

@Angelos, thank you! My familiarity with Kansai-ben is limited, I'm afraid. I might know more about Old Japanese than Kansai-ben at this point.
